# Flutter Installation error , When running 'flutter doctor'

Tags: flutter

I installed flutter SDK on my MacBook Air. When I run flutter doctor I am getting the following errors. How to fix it? [Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bU1xw.png)

Comment: Flutter doctor gives you several url links related to the errors. Have you tried them?

Comment: You can get the answer to your question over here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72736407/downloaded-executables-cannot-execute-on-host-macos-monterey-12-4-silicon-chi>